# How to retrieve data that matches a firebase userID

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Below is the data in my firebase database, I would like to obtain the 'doctorDetails' for a user by using his firebase userID.

Database structure: doctors/ userID/ doctorDetails

```
// Data in Database :

{
  "doctors" : {
    "65smvSYkhfVBtM2GrPmOl3cdgDy1" : {
      "doctorDetails" : {
        "designation" : "Principal Scientist",
        "docRegNumber" : "242354",
        "doctorName" : "Dr Nicole Tesla",
        "doctorVerified" : false,
        "mobileNumber" : "970050 8070",
        "specialization" : "Physicist"
      }
    },
    "FOCSwhfIZSOpqUgueoWlakSkVYr1" : {
      "doctorDetails" : {
        "designation" : "Principal Scientist",
        "docRegNumber" : "87509",
        "doctorName" : "Dr Curie ",
        "doctorVerified" : false,
        "mobileNumber" : "80690 00343",
        "specialization" : "Physicist"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Below is the code that I am using to obtain 'doctorDetails' by using their firebase userID.

```
var userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;     
firebase.database().ref('doctors/'+userId+'/doctorDetails').on('value', function(snapshot){
    console.log(snapshot.val());
});
```

However, I am still unable to obtain the 'doctor details' for a user with userID, can someone please suggest where I am going wrong ?

[EDIT 1]
The above code only listens for changes, how can I extract data without attaching a listener.

[EDIT 2]
Here are the permissions I've set, what changes do I need to make to be able to read the data ?

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    },
    "doctors":{
        "$uid": {
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You must see this [https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/836OyVNd_Yg](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/836OyVNd_Yg)

Comment: have you debugged your userId? looking in the code your firebase call should be working fine.

Comment: I am able to log the userId.

Comment: Attach an error listener to `on()` by adding a second callback `, function(error) { console.error(error); })` and it may tell you what's wrong.

Comment: I get this error: permission_denied at /doctors/FOCSwhfIZSOatgwesbs FWRF/doctorDetails: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with my database rules:

Old database rules

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    },
    "doctors":{
        "$uid": {
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Updated the database rules (in databases.rules.json) to the below which helped resolved the issue

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    },
    "doctors":{
        "$uid": {
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```